# OpenSSH server installation results in error E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Tags: ubuntu, apt, openssh

I tried installing OpenSSH server on Ubuntu 16.04 like this:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

However, it shows the message below:

> ```
> dell@dell-Latitude-E6400:~$ sudo apt-get install openssh-server
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree       
> Reading state information... Done
> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
> requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
> distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
> or been moved out of Incoming.
> The following information may help to resolve the situation:
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>  openssh-server : Depends: openssh-client (= 1:7.2p2-4) but 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.8 is to be installed
>                   Depends: openssh-sftp-server but it is not going to be installed
>                   Recommends: ncurses-term but it is not going to be installed
>                   Recommends: ssh-import-id but it is not going to be installed
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
> ```

Comment: Anyone please help me to resolve this error

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [ubuntu.se] or [unix.se] instead of here.

Answer (score 25):

Try this one this works for me.

```
sudo apt purge openssh-client
```

Actually openssh-client is installed on your system you have to first delete it and then install openssh-server with this command.

```
sudo apt install openssh-server
```

Comment: wonderful, thanks! solved it immediately